# Unable to do ssh with custom user & pem key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have created custom user on my EC2 Linux instance and created `.pub` and `.pem` key files. Please find the steps below. But unfortunately, I am not able to access my EC2 instance with the pem key.

Steps to create custom user and `.pub` and `.pem` key:

```
ssh-keygen -b 1024 -f svc-u-dcpeimg -t dsa
chmod 600 svc-u-dcpeimg.pub
useradd -c "image dcp" svc-u-dcpeimg
cd /home/svc-u-dcpeimg/
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
chown svc-u-dcpeimg:svc-u-dcpeimg .ssh
cat /bin/svc-u-dcpeimg.pub \>\> .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
chown svc-u-dcpeimg:svc-u-dcpeimg .ssh/authorized_keys
cat /bin/svc-u-dcpeimg \>\> /home/svc-u-dcpeimg/svc-u-dcpeimg.pem
chmod 600 svc-u-dcpeimg.pem
ssh -i svc-u-dcpeimg.pem svc-u-dcpeimg@ec2-ipaddress
```

Error message:

```
\[root@ip- svc-u-dcpeimg\]# ssh -i svc-u-dcpeimg.pem svc-u-dcpeimg@ec2-ip
svc-u-dcpeimg@ec2ip: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

My `cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
\[root@ip-172-20-0-48 svc-u-dcpeimg\]# cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.104 2021/07/02 05:11:21 dtucker Exp $
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.
# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.
# To modify the system-wide sshd configuration, create a  \*.conf  file under
# /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/  which will be automatically included below
Include /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/\*.conf
# If you want to change the port on a SELinux system, you have to tell
# SELinux about this change.
# semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp #PORTNUMBER
# 
\#Port 22
\#AddressFamily any
\#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
\#ListenAddress ::

###### 

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying

\#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging

\#SyslogFacility AUTH
\#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

\#LoginGraceTime 2m
\#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
\#StrictModes yes
\#MaxAuthTries 6
\#MaxSessions 10
\############
\#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
\#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
\#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust \~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
\#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's \~/.rhosts and \~/.shosts files
\#IgnoreRhosts yes
# Explicitly disable PasswordAuthentication. By presetting it, we
# avoid the cloud-init set_passwords module modifying sshd_config and
# restarting sshd in the default instance launch configuration.
PasswordAuthentication no
\#######
\#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
\#KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes

# Kerberos options

\#KerberosAuthentication no
\#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
\#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
\#KerberosGetAFSToken no
\#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
\#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
\#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
\#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the KbdInteractiveAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via KbdInteractiveAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and KbdInteractiveAuthentication to 'no'.
# WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Fedora and may cause several
# problems.

UsePAM yes

\#AllowAgentForwarding yes
\#AllowTcpForwarding yes
\#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
\#X11DisplayOffset 10
\#X11UseLocalhost yes
\#PermitTTY yes
\#PrintMotd yes
\#PrintLastLog yes
\#TCPKeepAlive yes
\#PermitUserEnvironment no
\#Compression delayed
\#ClientAliveInterval 0
\#ClientAliveCountMax 3
\#UseDNS no
\#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
\#MaxStartups 10:30:100
\#PermitTunnel no
\#ChrootDirectory none
\#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path

\#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems

Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis

\#Match User anoncvs

# X11Forwarding no
# AllowTcpForwarding no
# PermitTTY no
# ForceCommand cvs server

AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ec2-instance-connect
```

Changed few settings in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file - the file details provided above.

Comment: A keypair should be specified **when launching the Amazon EC2 instance**. The public key will then be copied to the appropriate `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the Linux instance. This way, only you will be able to login to the instance since only you have the private part of the key. From your code provided, it would seem that you created the keypair and then immediately attempted to access the instance. This won't work since the keypair wasn't specified when the instance was launched. (Otherwise _anybody_ could create a keypair and attempt to login to your instance!)